# Estimating the length of the arc $f(x) = 8x - x^{2}, 0 \leq x \leq 8.$

Tags: calculus

I have developed a formula in order to estimate the length of the arc $f(x) = 8x - x^{2}, 0 \leq x \leq 8,$ but I am unsure as to whether or not it is accurate.

It is:

$$d \sum_{k = 0}^{8d}{\sqrt{d^{2} + |f(d + k) - f(k)|^{2}}}, d \to 0.$$

According to [Desmos Graphing Calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/), the length of the arc is approximately $63.8009559368,$ where $d = 10^{-7},$ as, even at this relatively large interval, the calculator begins to break.

Does this formula look at all correct?

P.S. I suppose that, if one were to generalize this formula, it would be written as:

$$d \sum_{k = a}^{bd}{\sqrt{d^{2} + |f(d + k) - f(k)|^{2}}}, d \to 0,$$

which would measure the length of the graph $f(x)$ within the range $a \leq x \leq b.$

Comment: the two sides of the isosceles triangle $(0,0), (4, 16), (8,0)$ is $8\sqrt{17} = 32.98.$  it is a lower bound for the arc length. i would expect something closer to this; not $63.80.$ i did the integral $2\int_0^4 \sqrt{1+(8-2x)^2}\, dx = 33.637$

Comment: strange. according to my calculations it should be 33.63: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%2865-32t%2B4t%5E2%29%5E0.5dt+between+0+and+8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [arc length integration formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating),
$$ s = \int_0^8 \sqrt{1+(8-2x)^2} dx \approx 33.637 $$
As seen [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E8%20%5Csqrt%7B1%2B%288-2x%29%5E2%7D%20dx)

Your formula doesn't make sense to me because $k$ is the summation index, which ought to be an integer, and the upper limit being $bd$ makes it approach zero as well. If you meant $b/d$ as the end limit, then that would be more reasonable. Basically, you want to choose a set of uniformly spaced $x$ values from $a$ to $b$, with spacing $d$. Assuming $N = (b-a)/d$ is an integer, then your sum should run from $k=0,\ldots,N$, and the functions should be evaluated at the $k$-th $x$ value, which is $a + (b-a)k/N$, and the $k+1$-th value, which is not as you have written it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are, more or less, just computing the Riemann sums for the integral that gives the wanted length:

$$ L = \int_{0}^{8}\sqrt{1+(8-2x)^2}\,dx = \color{red}{4\sqrt{65}+\frac{1}{2}\log\left(8+\sqrt{65}\right)}=33.637267133556\ldots$$